# Unable to login with Google OAuth when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I am unable to login to the app when deployed to Heroku.  I had a successful build and deployment, but when I launch the app it starts me logged out and upon attempting to login, it hangs and throws an Application error.
Express/Passport/MongoDB + create-react-app

I chek my keys several time, everesting match perfect. On my localserver everesing working perfect. Can it be a problem with "https" response on server?

app link  https://mysterious-thicket-20426.herokuapp.com/

git repo https://github.com/detoner777/email-feedback-app

heroku err logs:

2019-08-20T09:44:08.211815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/auth/google/callback?code=4%2FpAFASjHeS_JuqGKXbEIDY4Jh5zHBJZk-Zyg19q6DHWGVtuipmCKVt1hLpwKltJUHW9XB3EBLcPGorEQUI68uZCE&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&session_state=330af188f3789437fd21ab099ebe776784cfe500..3fb5&prompt=none" host=mysterious-thicket-20426.herokuapp.com request_id=59b62556-d07c-42ae-8f7f-e89b3ab5b735 fwd="31.134.127.229" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-08-20T09:52:03.838240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=mysterious-thicket-20426.herokuapp.com request_id=81a31581-1aa6-478d-98af-68b6c479e32a fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=289 protocol=https

```
//inex.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app);


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);


// passport.js
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: keys.googleClientID,
            clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
            callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
            proxy: true
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

            if (existingUser) {
                return done(null, existingUser);
            }

            const user = await User({ googleID: profile.id }).save()
            done(null, user);
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Did you updated callback URL in google dashboard?

Comment: Yes http://prntscr.com/ov1h6o

Comment: Did you add environment variables in the Heroku Dashboard?

Comment: yes and i checkt all keys 
http://prntscr.com/ov20dd

Comment: In `keys.js` `NODE_ENV === 'production'`  but in heroku node environment varaible is not set.
Please check if in heroku default NODE_ENV is production

Comment: I read that 'production' is the default
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, here's what worked for me:

Please check that your user/password for the Mongodb Atlas prod database correctly match the MONGO_URI variable that you set in Heroku, that was causing this issue for me. I think it's easy to make a typo here since you cannot see the password for the database user after you create it. Also note that the user should not be "read-only", and that this is not the same user/password combination that you use to log in to Mongodb Atlas.

I found that the reason why the authentication callback was failing with a timeout error was that the Google Strategy's callback defined in the file passport.js never called the method done(). This, in turn, happened because the query to find a user in the MongoDB never completed because Mongoose couldn't connect to the mlab.com database. I tried creating a new user for the prod database in mlab and updating that in the Heroku environment variables and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding full url  of server as callback url,
 check the documentation 
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/ , so your callback

URL will be `https://mysterious-thicket-20426.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback`

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem as you with the same setup and everything.

I checked everything and noticed the my cluster on MongoDB had no activity and was paused. The cluster pauses when there are no connection made to it after a while.
This meant the backend wasn't able to properly to the database, hence the timeout to `/auth/google/callback`.

### Here's what happened:

After you've go through the OAuth credential on `/auth/google` page, google redirects you back to `/auth/google/callback`.

The route handler for `/auth/google/callback` endpoint picks up the request and uses the `passport.authenticate('google')` middleware (to verify the authentication)

Your `passport.authenticate('google')` middleware uses the **Google Strategy** and its configurations you've set up inside `passport.js`

Going back on the no connections made to your database issue, this means there will be an authentication problem within the Google Strategy. Specifically, in its callback function:

> ```js
> async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
>   const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
>
>   if (existingUser) {
>     return done(null, existingUser);
>   }
>
>   const user = await User({ googleID: profile.id }).save()
>   done(null, user);
> }
> ```

Express app wasn't able to make a connection to the MongoDB earlier, and now it attempts to execute a promise: `await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })` **with no error handling**.
This means there should an `unhandled promise rejection error` appearing in your console and your app crashing down.

Like @Agasthian Rathinavel mentioned, do double check on your MongoDB credentials and the environmental variables so you're certain the backend is able to connect to the database.